# A system with Deep Freeze loses data on non-frozen drives

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, deep-freeze

My client sells an industrial application that runs on a custom system with multiple drives and partitions on those drives. Drive C: is frozen with Deep Freeze, but the other drives are not frozen. Drives D-F are used for data storage and retrieval by my client's industrial application.

The issue is that without Deep Freeze installed, I can run the application, which saves new data to the E: drive. I can kill the power to the system, boot back up, and the data has been written to the E: drive properly. However, with Deep Freeze installed, and only C: frozen/thawed (the operating system lives there), the same procedure leaves me with data loss. Files that seem to be present on the drive before the forced power-off, are gone after power loss and boot. I can repeat this over and over again, ad nauseum, with the same result: with DF, data loss, without DF, no data loss.

Any ideas? Does DF interfere with NTFS's journaling capability? Does it have some sort of caching mechanism for non-frozen drives? If so, is there any way of defeating this for drives that aren't frozen?

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited for Deep Freeze support.

Comment: Reading through [this guide](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/document-library/document/deep-freeze-retaining-user-data_en-uk/) it seems like you may need to keep the D and F drives in a thawed state instead of not being managed by Deep Freeze at all.

Answer (score 1):

when FIRST installing DF you are given a choice of which drives/partitions will be affected.  Be certain that only the check box for drive "C" is checked and all other drives/partitions NOT checked.